# React native navigation: Unable to navigate to the top screen in the stack

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

My current navigation looks like this

Top Level Stack

- Login Screen
- Main App Stack

  - Home Stack
  - Search
  - Settings Tab Stack

    - Settings screen

Im trying to have a sign out button in the settings screen, which when pressed would navigate to the Login Screen

Currently it gives an error
**The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Login"} was not handled by any navigator.**

The sign out button code

```
<View style={{alignSelf: "center"}}>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate("Login") }}>
    <Text>Sign Out</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

This is how my top level stack looks like

```
<NavigationContainer>  
    
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Login"
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'white', height: ScreenHeigth * 0 },
          headerTintColor: '#fff',
      }}>
          
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ title: '', headerLeft: null, gestureEnabled: false }}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={Main} options={{ title: '', headerLeft: null, gestureEnabled: false}} />

      
      </Stack.Navigator>
          
    </NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **popToTop**?

I have changed some code **onPress** button in **signOut** view

```
<View style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>
   <TouchableOpacity
     onPress={() => {
     navigation.popToTop();
   }}
>
   <Text>Sign Out</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: it gives an error `The action 'POP_TO_TOP' was not handled by any navigator.` I also tried using `navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop())` but I got the same error

Comment: I think login navigation must be in Main navigation stack then it may work because login and main stack are different stacks that why the stack did not get it.

Comment: So there is no way that I can navigate to a higher level stack ?

Comment: can you show me how to make a stack navigator here? https://codeshare.io/axWlzk

Comment: you can also provide code from github so I can dive into and check properly